# Mysql database, can't connect

Tags: php, mysql

I've had this problem before, but I can't remember how I got over it. Basically I have a code something like this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

$grab = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Tables;");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($grab)){
    if($row['BasketId'] == $basketId){
        $total = $row['Total'];
    }
}
```

But I keep getting access denied for user @ localhost. The problem is that immediately before this php there is another php file with the exact same code and it connects and works fine. Why would this php file be different.

I've checked all the privileges and they are fine. Plus like I said there is an identical piece of code previously that works fine. For some reason this mysql doesn't like this php file. What could be the reason. I'm guessing that mysql is just buggy crap.

Comment: Just because something doesn't work doesn't mean it's "buggy crap". The problem is in 99.99% in your faulty implementation, the rest 0.01% is other developers who hadn't yet fixed known bugs. In your case the problem might be somewhere else. Carefully inspect your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have the code is really quite simple and like I said it's exactly the same as another piece. I keep checking but it's not going to magically change to something else.

Comment: Not only that, but the whole file is copied from another website where it was working. Only had to tweak a couple of things but there should be no error.

Comment: Is your first connection closed? By the way, if it is not, there is no need to initiate another one to the same database.

Comment: I don't close the first connection in that php file. But this is a different php file surely the connection closes after the php file closes. Do you think I should close the connection before a seprate webpage opens one.

Comment: No, the connection stays active! Always after you do a query in mysql close the connection. If you don't it also implies a lot of security risks and degraded performance

Comment: Oh, ok, so it is a different file and is not included or required by this one. Right? You should always close connections btw.

Comment: Tables;");, is the semi-column too early after Tables; <--- ?

Comment: I don't think so the semicolon is in the same place as the other file.

Comment: Have you tried using the root credential? - just to rule-out any issues caused by privilege or specific db user itself.

Comment: Sorry everyone, but like I said i copied the whole php file. There a change that needed to be made to get it working when I copied the file to a new website. and I was editing the wrong file. Sorry again.

Answer (score 0):

Test that you connection attempt has succeeded and if not report the error message, then you will knwo what is wrong.

Its also a good idea to make sure that error reporting is set to show errors on the web page, during development, assuming you are using a live server where error reporting will probably be turned off

Ripped off for the strangest place [*The PHP Manual*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)

```
<?php

php error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);


$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "database");

if (!$con ) {
    echo 'Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '
            . mysqli_connect_error();
    exit;
}
```